# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel for XmlTextReader

Tags: c#, winforms, tls1.2

I have searched and read all articles about this error before opening this question. I have also added all the required codes as suggested by answers found on here

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;    
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(url);
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(reader);
```

Here is the [URL](https://meteor.aihw.gov.au/xmlapi3.0/list.phtml/clientId/BarwonHealth/itemType/dataElement/count/100) that is giving me error. It's a public API. 
I tested my app on 2 Windows 7 machines and 3 Windows 10 machines. Both Win 7 and 1 Win 10 machines throw error. On both Win 7 machines, IE 11 cannot open the URL or even the homepage. TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 are ticked in IE Advanced setting. No problem on Chrome or FF though.

**Modified the code according to Jimi's suggestion:**

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient
{
    Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
};

wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.123 Safari/537.36");
string xmlString = string.Empty;
using (wc)
{
    xmlString = wc.DownloadString(url);
}
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);
```

Comment: Go to event viewer and look for schannel errors in the Security tab. Most likely your clients and the server can't negotiate a cipher.

Comment: The Server requires, for that connection, TLS1.3 and activates HSTS (Strict Security Transport).

Comment: It works for me on a standard Windows 10 machine (v1909), which suggests to me that you have a machine-level issue, not a code issue. Are you perhaps on a domain that is overriding your security settings via Group Policy?

Comment: @zaitsman There's no error in Security tab, but in System tab, there are a few of them show `A fatal error occurred while creating an SSL client credential. The internal error state is 10013.`

Comment: @Jimi, I tried adding `SecurityProtocolType.Tls13` to the `SecurityProtocol` and received a different error `The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.`

Comment: @yaakov, What policy should I check if this is the case?

Comment: It expects that an User-Agent header is specified. You can use the FF header. Depending on how the HSTS requests are handled, you may not be able to create a connection in Windows 7.

Comment: @Jimi, I modified the code and added user-agent string, didn't work on both Win 7 and 1 of the Win 10 machines

Comment: Download [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) and see whether you have TLS 1.3 available. You won't find it in Windows 7. To enable it in Windows 10, see [here](https://community.tenable.com/s/article/How-to-check-for-TLS-version-1-3-in-Linux-Windows-and-Chrome).

Comment: @Jimi, on the Windows 10 machine that is working, TLS 1.3 is unavailable

Comment: On a second look, it appears the Server also supports TLS 1.2 with standard ciphers (`TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` and `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`), but in this case, it should also work with Windows 10/IE11 (`RSA 2048 - SHA256`). Windows 7 machines won't work. Check the problematic Windows 10 machine.

Comment: @Jimi, the problematic Win 10 machine can open the URL via IE or Chome, but not my app. FIPS is disabled in registry and GPO. It runs on a Citrix server if it makes any different.